# How can i get all the elements from a website

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to write code for getting all elements from website url. But, in the out put I am getting only last element values and attribute values the code is like below

```
public static void getHTMLElements(List<String> urls) throws IOException {
    getElements(urls);
    for (Map.Entry<String, HtmlElements> entry1 : urlList.entrySet()) {
        HtmlElements htmlele = entry1.getValue();
        System.out.println("url is " + entry1.getKey());
        System.out.println("Element Name is " + htmlele.getElementName());
        System.out.println("Attributes are " + htmlele.getAttributes());
    }
}

public static void getElements(List<String> urls) throws IOException {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < urls.size(); i++) {
            String s = urls.get(i);
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(s).get();
            getInputElements(doc, s);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void getInputElements(Document doc, String urls) {
    // List l=new ArrayList();
    HtmlElements htmlElements = new HtmlElements();
    Properties attributes = new Properties();
    Elements elements = doc.getAllElements();
    for (Element element : elements) {
        if (!element.tagName().contains("script")) {
            String elementName = element.tagName();
            Attributes attr = element.attributes();
            for (Attribute attr1 : attr) {
                if (attr1.getKey().contains("id")) {
                    attributes.put(attr1.getKey(), attr1.getValue());
                }
                if (attr1.getKey().contains("name")) {
                    attributes.put(attr1.getKey(), attr1.getValue());
                }
                if (attr1.getKey().contains("type")) {
                    attributes.put(attr1.getKey(), attr1.getValue());
                }
            }
            htmlElements.setElementName(elementName);
            htmlElements.setAttributes(attributes);
        }
        urlList.put(urls, htmlElements);
    }
}
```

I am getting only last element values and last element attributes. Values were overridden and I am getting only last values. I want get all the elements and attributes.

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I'm not particularly familiar with Jsoup, but on first glance... it seems like `htmlElements` and `attributes` ought to be initialized inside the loop.

```
    public static void getInputElements(Document doc, String urls) {
        Elements elements = doc.getAllElements();
        for (Element element : elements) {
            HtmlElements htmlElements = new HtmlElements();
            Properties attributes = new Properties();
            // ...
```

Comment: I tried as you said.even though i didn't get proper values.i am getting only last element values.I want all the values out side the for loop